# EXTJS 6.2 how to update row in database after editing field on header?

Tags: extjs

I have Using Extjs6.2 header,if i insert data in each field,After save How to update database editing field on header.

Comment: What do you mean? What have you tried so far? What does this question have to do with jquery?